# Using class in arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm writing a class at the moment and i want to store a value in it. The code looks like this:

```
class A{
  private:
  bool ena;
  //...
  public:
  //...       

  void function(int x)
  {
    if(x == 1)// or x could equal anything
    {
      ena = 1;
    }
    if(x == 0) // x could equal anything
    {
      ena = 0;
    }

    if((x == 5) && (ena == 1))
    {
      //...part1.....
    }
    //       .....other parts...    
  }
};
```

As you can see i want to enable or disable some part of this function by calling this first with 1 or 0. But after i enabled it the "ena" variable loses ist value when the function is called again. How could i solve this to store that boolean valuein my class?

Thanks guys.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean. How does ena lose its value? It's a class member variable.

Comment: The statement `ena == 0;` is not going to change `ena`, and should be generating a compiler warning. That line should be `ena = 0;`

Comment: You' re right, i copied it incorrectly to the forum

Comment: Ok, but that code should work, so you need to show the code that uses the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake most likely is to use `==` comparison instead of `=` assignment.

```
class A {
    bool ena;  // doesn't have to be public so far
public:
    void function(int x)
    {
        if(x == 0) // x could equal anything
        {
            ena = true;
            //  ^   not ==
        }
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
A a;
a.function(0);
// now A.ena is true
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I edited my post since then.
As the code runs, i can see right after the if(x==1)... that the ena's value is set to 1, but after the function is called again, it's already 0.

Comment: @Abotric Your class looks fine. So it's probably the way you use the class that's wrong. That means you need to show us the code that uses this class. Perhaps you're creating an instance in loop(), which ofcourse means it'll be destroyed for the next loop() perhaps you do something else strange.

Comment: I'm using this way:  A a;     a.function(num);
And there's anything else that could modify this.

Comment: @Abotric we cannot help you more based on the code you posted, with my  correction - it should work, you must be doing something wrong what your code doesn't show us. Where and how is your A instance created? Isn't this local variable created in loop maybe?

Comment: It's outside everything (not in the loop() nor in the setup() )

Comment: Can you please paste complete snippet?

Comment: I wrote to this forum because i thought that i cannot store a value in "ena" so i need a solution for my problem and somebody could help me here.
But as u stated about this code "it should work" - i get the answer for my  question. It means that the main part looks fine and there is some mistyping or something that i have to find- and i can do that.
So thanks for making me confident about storing a value in the "ena".